# Java lock (synchronize) global variable

Tags: java

I have a code

```
public class Exec {

    private String string = "";

    public void start() {
        MyThread t = new MyThread();
        MyThread2 t2 = new MyThread2();
        t.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    private class MyThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                string = "1";

                System.out.println(string);
                try {
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyThread2 extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                string = "2";

                System.out.println(string);
                try {
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing hard this. 2 Threads print a value.

Output :

```
1
2
1
2
1
...
```

The question how i can lock global variable(resource)? to make output :

```
1
1
1
1
...
2
2
2
2
...
```

Comment: For your expected output, why don't you remove thread concept and directly call both methods one after another.

Comment: @NamanGala i would try to resolve multi-thread conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to change `start()` to `run()` as you effectively don't want multiple threads.

However you can use this

```
synchronized(Exec.class) {
```

or

```
synchronized(System.out) {
```

as a shared global object, or you can pass such an object.

Comment: This will not guarantee that the t thread will get the lock first, even if it's started as the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Before starting the second thread (or after starting it, but before getting into the `for` loop) you can invoke `t.join()` which will block until `t` is done.

Comment: I think this is the best and the clearest solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a lock variable and lock on this variable.

```
public class Exec {

    private String string = "";
    private Object globalLock = new Object();  // The global lock  

    public void start() {
        MyThread t = new MyThread(globalLock);
        MyThread2 t2 = new MyThread2(globalLock);
        t.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    private class MyThread extends Thread {
        private Object lock;

        public MyThread(Object lock) {
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized(lock) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    string = "1";
                    System.out.println(string);
                    try {
                        sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyThread2 extends Thread {
        private Object lock;

        public MyThread2(Object lock) {
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized(lock) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    string = "2";
                    System.out.println(string);
                    try {
                        sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not guarantee that the `t` thread will get the lock first, even if it's started as the first one.

Comment: No, it guarantees that first operating thread completes before second starts. If there is a sequence it is not necessary to use two threads. One thread with the combination of the two run code will suffice.

Comment: There is a compilation error in your code. MyThread2 does not take lock as constructor argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Exec{
private String string = "";
Object lock = new Object();
    public void start() {
        MyThread t = new MyThread();
        MyThread2 t2 = new MyThread2();
        t.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyServer().start();
    }

    private class MyThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lock) {


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                string = "1";

                System.out.println(string);
                try {
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            }
        }


    }

    private class MyThread2 extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lock) {


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                string = "2";

                System.out.println(string);
                try {
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it does not make sense to use multi-threading when you want to execute code blocks sequentially, still if you want it you can solve this problem in multiple ways. You can use locking mechanism (internal, external, any of the `Lock` interface implementation etc.), synchronizer etc. Simplest way IMO is to use volatile variable:

```
public class Exec{
    private volatile boolean lock = false;

    private String string = "";

    public void start() {
        MyThread t = new MyThread();
        MyThread2 t2 = new MyThread2();
        lockResource();
        t.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    void lockResource() {
        lock = true;
    }

    void releaseResource() {
        lock = false;
    }

    private class MyThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!lock) ;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                string = "1";

                System.out.println(string);
                try {
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            releaseResource();
        }
    }

    private class MyThread2 extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (lock) ;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                string = "2";
                System.out.println(string);
                try {
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here first thread will keep on printing as boolean variable `lock` is false, while the other threads has while loop to keep waiting. Once first thread is done it will set boolean to true and this change will be seen by other thread as well because `lock` is volatile.